# Have a bootstrapped data object but want the sum of observations per trial not overall aggregate in rstudio

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, simulation, statistics-bootstrap

I have the following data object:

```
 require(tidyverse)
    sample(x = 0:1, size = 4, replace = TRUE) %>% sum()
```

I have created a bootstrap simulation of this code by using the replicate function (we were simulating coin tosses and heads50 is the final data object):

```
heads50 <- replicate(50, sample(0:1, 4, TRUE)) %>% sum()
```

However, when I run the sum function it gives me the total aggregate number of heads over all replications of this experiment, not the output of each trial (i.e. how many heads when tossing the coin 4 times per trial is what I want to know, not just the overall number so I can plot probability later on)

I've also created a data object to try to group by possibilities (i.e. to calculate probability of tossing one heads v 2 heads v 3 heads v 4 heads out of four in a trial) like so:

```
data50 <- tibble(heads = heads50) %>% 
group_by(heads) %>% 
summarise(n = n(), p=n/50)
```

Problem is it is not doing that when I try to generate a histogram, but just giving me a sum overall probability with one bar:

```
    ggplot(data50, aes(x = heads, y = p)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "green") +
  labs(x = "Number of Heads", y = "Probability of Heads in 4 flips(p)") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Anyone have an idea of how to sum each trial and separate out the possibilities? I have tried to restart rstudio and reload the tidyverse package, which includes dplyr with the 6 core functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is when you're calling the `sum()` function. When the `sum()` is outside `replicate()`, what happens is that `replicate()` will make a 4x50 matrix of zeros and ones, and then `sum()` will just flatten it and add it all up. Instead, what you want is a sum taken on a per-trial basis; we want to do the addition within the replication loop, not outside it. Try:

```
heads50 <- replicate(50, sample(0:1, size = 4, replace = T) %>% sum)
```

Another option would be to sum your matrix only along columns; that is,

```
heads50 <- replicate(50, sample(0:1, size = 4, replace = T)) %>% colSums
```

where this time the `colSums()` function sits outside the `replicate()` as it did in your original example.

Comment: Thanks, did the trick. Used the first argument and brought sum within the replicate loop, but good to know that you also have the option to sum the matrix along columns as well.

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron has pointed it out correctly. You don't really need a pipe to sum up your counts. You can write it as the following, or if you are familiar with the binomial distribution, what you have is essentially, `rbinom(50,4,0.5)`.

So below I kind of wrote your code again to simulate and plot. Hopefully its useful in some ways:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

data.frame(trial=1:50) %>% 
mutate(heads=rbinom(50,4,0.5)) %>%
count(heads) %>% 
mutate(p=n/sum(n)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=heads,y=p)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="green") + 
labs(x="Number of heads",y="Probability of Heads in 4 flips(p)") + 
theme_minimal()
```

[image]